# PHP Populating Values from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "change_management";    
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);  
$query3 = "SELECT `change_id` FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE `review_by` IS NULL";    
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query3);
?>    
<select name="change_id">
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['change_id']."'</option>";
}
?>    
</select>
```

As you can see, I am trying to populate the drop down menu with `change_id` values where the field `review_by` IS NULL. At the moment, the drop down menu has blank values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "<option value='".$row['change_id']."'>Value</option>"; Try using this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed **visible** value in `<option>Your value here</option>`

Try changing

```
echo "<option value='".$row['change_id']."'</option>";
```

To

```
echo "<option value='".$row['change_id']."'>".$row['change_id']."</option>";
```

Comment: Simple question, simple answer. Thanks a lot!